# rounding two math calculations don't add up like they should

Tags: sql-server

Why doesn't this

```
select round(17 * .235, 2), round(17 * (1-.235), 2)
```

return

> 4.00 and 13.00

instead of

> 4.00 and 13.01

Also,

```
select CONVERT(Decimal(19,2), 17 * .235), CONVERT(Decimal(19,2), 17 * (1-.235))
```

returns

> 4.00 and 13.01

How can I force the two calculations to add up to the starting number (17.00)?

Comment: But it looks like select round(17 * .235, 0.01), round(17 * (1-.235), 0.01) works. Have I been using ROUND wrong for a long time?

Comment: if you want to truncate the points ,use round(17*.235 , 0) then the result will be 13.000. but the second parameter has been defined 2 then it round into 2 points, and that's correct. if you round a number  11.532 with 2 points (like select round(11.532 ,2 )),the result is  11.530 and with 1 point , the result would be 11.500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that SQL rounds AWAY FROM ZERO. Which is different from VB's rounding (ROUND TOWARDS EVEN). At least that's the way I read this:
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-rounding-methods/

Comment: Yes, with two numbers that sum to an integer the two roundings toward even would normally cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(17 * .235 as float)
      ,cast(17 * (1-.235) as float)
      ,cast(17 * .235 as float)+cast(17 * (1-.235) as float)
```

Returns

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
3.995               13.005              17
```

If you don't like float, try decimal   (some folks hate float, me not so much)

```
select cast(17 * .235 as decimal(18,9))
      ,cast(17 * (1-.235) as decimal(18,9))
      ,cast(17 * .235 as decimal(18,9))+cast(17 * (1-.235) as decimal(18,9))
```

Comment: I think float is the worst choice for precision -- it is always approximate, isn't it? I need the numbers to round to dollars and cents. So 3.995 should be 4.00 and 13.005 should be 13.00. Round to the nearest number, 5 rounds to the nearest even number, is what I'm seeing in the documentation.

Comment: I should add, you are rounding to 2 decimals, yet your calculations go to 3 decimals.  In such cases, rounding will always run the risk of a "Gestalt Violation"

Comment: Another option is T-Y=X   This way you can use the rounding as desired

Comment: I thought the ROUND and CONVERT functions would eliminate the third place to the right of the decimal. At least, I've always thought they did that in the past. But it appears I've been thinking about this incorrectly. How would you write the statement for the "T-Y=X"? select 17*.235, 17 - (17*.235) you mean?

Comment: select CONVERT(Decimal(19,2), 17 * .235), CONVERT(Decimal(19,2), 17 - (17 * .235)) gives me 4.00 and 13.01.

Comment: select ROUND(17 * .235, 2), 17 - ROUND(17 * .235, 2) gives me 4.00 and 13.00, though.

Comment: select round(17 * .235, 2), round(17 * (1-.235), 2) gives me 4.00 and 13.01 because the result is 13.005.  Even Decimal will extend the precision as necessary (2 decimals becomes 4), and guess what happens when the product goes into a decimal(n,2).... It is rounded.  This is why I am sooooo tired of people bashing float.

Comment: Select cast(1.005 as decimal(5,2))  returns 1.01